# UPDATE em coluna com JOIN em tabela temporária utilizando WITH

Tags: postgresql

Olá, gostaria de saber como fazer o update do campo valor da tabela abaixo, utilizando uma tabela temporária criada a partir de um array, que possui os valores padrões para cada parâmetro.

Tabela a ser atualizada a coluna **valor**:

| id | ip | parametro | valor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 192.168.10.161 | imprimir | 1 |
| 2 | 192.168.10.161 | ajustar | 0 |
| 3 | 192.168.10.161 | adicionar | 1 |
| 4 | 192.168.10.161 | modificar | 1 |
| 5 | 192.168.10.161 | cancelar | 0 |
| 6 | 192.168.10.161 | colunas | 10011 |
| 7 | 192.168.11.110 | imprimir | 1 |
| 8 | 192.168.11.110 | ajustar | 0 |
| 9 | 192.168.11.110 | adicionar | 1 |
| 10 | 192.168.11.110 | modificar | 1 |
| 11 | 192.168.11.110 | cancelar | 0 |
| 12 | 192.168.11.110 | colunas | 10011 |
| 13 | 192.168.11.178 | imprimir | 1 |
| 14 | 192.168.11.178 | ajustar | 0 |
| 15 | 192.168.11.178 | adicionar | 1 |
| 16 | 192.168.11.178 | modificar | 1 |
| 17 | 192.168.11.178 | cancelar | 0 |
| 18 | 192.168.11.178 | colunas | 10011 |

Tabela com os valores padrões para atualizar:

| parametro | padrao |
| --- | --- |
| imprimir | 1 |
| ajustar | 1 |
| adicionar | 1 |
| modificar | 1 |
| cancelar | 1 |
| colunas | 11111 |

Criei a tabela acima com o SQL:

```
select unnest(array['imprimir', 'ajustar', 'adicionar', 
'modificar', 'cancelar', 'colunas']) "param",
unnest(array[1,1,1,1,2,11111])"padrao"
```

estou tentando fazer o update com o seguinte SQL:

```
with pdr as (select unnest(array['imprimir', 'ajustar', 'adicionar',
'modificar', 'cancelar', 'colunas']) "param",
unnest(array[1,1,1,1,2,11111])"padrao")
update prmestac as p
inner join pdr a 
on a."param" = p.parametro
set p.valor = a."padrao" 
where p.parametro = a."param"
```

Mas esta dando erro no join.

Poderiam me dar alguma dica?

Segue sqlfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f5188/28

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo a documentação do [update](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) do PostgreSQL:

```
[ WITH [ RECURSIVE ] with_query [, ...] ]
UPDATE [ ONLY ] table_name [ * ] [ [ AS ] alias ]
    SET { column_name = { expression | DEFAULT } |
          ( column_name [, ...] ) = [ ROW ] ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) |
          ( column_name [, ...] ) = ( sub-SELECT )
        } [, ...]
    [ FROM from_item [, ...] ]
    [ WHERE condition | WHERE CURRENT OF cursor_name ]
    [ RETURNING * | output_expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...] ]
```

Especificamente em **FROM from_item**, traduzido por https://translate.google.com.br/?hl=pt-BR:

"Uma expressão de tabela que permite que colunas de outras tabelas apareçam na condição WHERE e expressões de atualização. Isso usa a mesma sintaxe que a cláusula FROM de uma instrução SELECT; por exemplo, um alias para o nome da tabela pode ser especificado."

Resumindo, você pode informar o nome do seu [with](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) no from e usá-lo para definir os valores do update, sem fazer o [join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html).

Código para criação dos dados e reprodução:

```
create temp table prmestac as
select 1 as id, '192.168.10.161' as ip, 'imprimir' as parametro, 1 as valor;

delete from prmestac;

insert into prmestac (id, ip, parametro, valor) values 
(1, '192.168.10.161', 'imprimir', 1),
(2, '192.168.10.161', 'ajustar', 0),
(3, '192.168.10.161', 'adicionar', 1),
(4, '192.168.10.161', 'modificar', 1),
(5, '192.168.10.161', 'cancelar', 0),
(6, '192.168.10.161', 'colunas', 10011),
(7, '192.168.11.110', 'imprimir', 1),
(8, '192.168.11.110', 'ajustar', 0),
(9, '192.168.11.110', 'adicionar', 1),
(10, '192.168.11.110', 'modificar', 1),
(11, '192.168.11.110', 'cancelar', 0),
(12, '192.168.11.110', 'colunas', 10011),
(13, '192.168.11.178', 'imprimir', 1),
(14, '192.168.11.178', 'ajustar', 0),
(15, '192.168.11.178', 'adicionar', 1),
(16, '192.168.11.178', 'modificar', 1),
(17, '192.168.11.178', 'cancelar', 0),
(18, '192.168.11.178', 'colunas', 10011);

--select * from prmestac;

with pdr as (select unnest(array['imprimir', 'ajustar', 'adicionar',
'modificar', 'cancelar', 'colunas']) "param",
unnest(array[1,1,1,1,2,11111])"padrao")

--select * from pdr

update prmestac 
set valor = pdr.padrao 
from pdr
where parametro = pdr.param;
```

Parte mais relevante:

```
update prmestac 
set valor = pdr.padrao 
from pdr
where parametro = pdr.param;
```

Comment: Muito bom, foi certinho. Obrigado

Comment: Disponha, ainda bem que a resposta ajudou.